# MVC WebApi not using AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a mixed MVC 4 app, where some controllers are regular implementations of `Controller` and some controllers are implementations of `ApiController`.  I'm also using Autofac for DI, but it appears that the WebApi controller "activator" machinery (for lack for a more specific term) is not using the Autofac resolver (`AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`), which leads to an exception being thrown when I make a request against one of my api controllers.  Here's the error:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>
        Type 'MyApp.Areas.Api.Controllers.MyController' does not have a default constructor
    </ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
        at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) 
        at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType) 
        at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) 
        at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    </StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Here's how I set it up:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

My understanding of the Autofac.WebApi integrations is that the above is the only requirement for getting WebApi to use the Autofac resolver, so what might be going on?

*side note*: The only goofy part of this that I can think of that might have bearing is that I have WebApi controllers in an MVC Area which isn't supported by the `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`, so implemented a custom one (vis-à-vis [Andrew Malkov](http://netmvc.blogspot.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html%20%22Andrew%20Malkov%22%29)).  I don't intuit that this would have any bearing on the resolver, though, because the selector only returns a type which is later used in activation.

Comment: Have you registered your WebApi controllers in your ContainerBuilder with the `builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` method call?

Comment: @nemesv Thank you!  That's what I had forgotten.  Write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To setup Autofac for Web.API you need to do two things:

1. Register the Autofac dependency resolver (in the App_Start):

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
       new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
   ```
2. And register your Api controllers in your container builder with the call:

   ```
   containerBuilder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this blog can help you: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/07/16/dependency-injection-with-asp-net-web-api-and-autofac.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but that article only repeats a more thorough explanation for doing what I've already done.  That's useful in itself, but it doesn't really move the ball for me on this.